# Error Reporting via Mail in a Zend 2 Application

Tags: php, error-handling, zend-framework2

I'm customizing a large Zend 2 Application called VuFind. For our production system, I want error reporting via mail. I created a file `error_reporting.php` which is included in `index.php` at the top (before the Zend2 stuff)

```
require_once('error_reporting.php');
```

Here is the most important content of this file. I left out the function `parseErrorNo()` because is just a display method.

```
<?php
//DEV Mode
if(APPLICATION_ENV == 'development') {
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL );    
}
//Testing
elseif(APPLICATION_ENV == 'test') {
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL - E_NOTICE );    
}
//Production mode
else {
    ini_set('display_errors', false);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', false);
    ini_set('log_errors', true);
    ini_set('error_log', '/var/log/vufind.log');
    error_reporting(0);
}
set_error_handler("bszErrorHandler", E_ERROR);

/**
 * Send mail  to admins
 * @param int $errNo
 * @param string $errStr
 */
function bszErrorHandler($errNo, $errStr) {
    $recipients = [
        'my@mail.de',
    ];
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $subject = 'Error on '.$host.': '.utf8_decode($errStr);
    $error = error_get_last();
    $file = isset($error) ? $error['file'] : '';
    $line = isset($error) ? $error['line'] : '';
    $msg = isset($error) ? $error['message'] : '';
    $message = [
        'Error Code: '.parseErrorNo($errNo), 
        'Query String: '.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],
        'Remote Addr: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'Server Port: '.$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'],
        'User Agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
    ];
    if(isset($error)) {
        $message['file'] = $file;
        $message['line'] = $line;
        $message['message'] = $msg;
    }
    foreach ($recipients as $address) {
        mail($address, $subject, utf8_decode(implode("\n", $message)));
    }    
}
```

This works when I'm triggering an `E_USER_*` but it does not work when there is a real exception or fatal PHP error. I guess  this is somewhere catched in Zend; maybe for logging? But I could not find a call of `set_error_handler()`. There is just one call in AjaxController, which is not responsible for the main application.

Code of VuFind can be seen here https://github.com/vufind-org/vufind

Regards,
powerriegel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `set_error_handler("bszErrorHandler", E_ERROR)` doesn't need to be called. You need to trigger it with an error. But it is only used for user-defined error function. This function is the reason you only receive mails on `E_USER_ERROR` not on real exceptions or fatal errors.

Comment: Thanks, that was not clear! I now found a logging setting in VuFind which allows to send mails.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this in `index.php`. You are polluting your index file. You could for example make a logger service. Environmental variables are available in the application through:

```
$currentEnvironment = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');
```

You can also use your view manager config to turn exceptions on and off.

In the Zend Framework 2 manual there is a chapter **[Advanced Configuration Tricks](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#advanced-configuration-tricks)** with a paragraph **[Environment-specific system configuration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-system-configuration)**. There you can see other examples on how to use environment variables to setup your application error handling.

Comment: This answer does not really answer my question. My question was not about environment variables but about error handling and why I get mails only on `E_USER_ERROR`not on real exceptions or fatal errors.

It's clear that I pollute my `index.php` but I don't worry.